# will not compile incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int [0]'

Tags: c++, arrays

here is my code:
CPP:

```
#include "../include/Enemy.h"

Enemy::Enemy(int X[], int Y[], int Type )
{

    x=X;
    y=Y;
    type=Type;
}

Enemy::~Enemy()
{
    //dtor
}
```

Header:

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H
#define ENEMY_H


class Enemy
{
    public:
        Enemy(int X[], int Y[], int Type );
        virtual ~Enemy();
    protected:
    private:
        int type;
        int x[], y[];

};

#endif // ENEMY_H
```

I get the following error:

> ||In constructor 'Enemy::Enemy(int*, int*, int)':| |6|error:
>   incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int [0]'| |7|error:
>   incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int [0]'| ||=== Build
>   finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|

Can someone explain why this is and how to remedy it

Comment: 1. you can't assign to arrays, 2. arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays.

Comment: `int x[], y[];` This is illegal and should give an error before it even reaches the constructor definition. You must specify the size of the array. (You've done Java before, have you? :) )

Comment: I was about to suggest a `vector` or some other container which could be empty (but should it?), but then I had no idea what a list of x, y coordinates means here.

Comment: I forgot that arrays must have a specified size- I am using vectors

Comment: In a parameter declaration (and only in that context), `int X[], int Y[]` is perfectly legal, but it really means `int *X, int *Y`.

Comment: You say "I am using vectors". No, you aren't, at least not in the code you've shown us.

Comment: I meant that is what I have decided to do

Comment: I am well aware of what a vector is

Comment: What's happening here? Is there a meta question about this question? It has been bumped to the homepage, is there a reason?

Comment: @YSC IDK, looks like it was just bumped again.. I'm voting to delete, it's rubbish question and providing a viable answer would pretty much be writing a tutorial on how arrays work in C++ and rewrite OP's entire program.  (edit - it doesn't give me option to delete, so I've chosen "too broad" for aforementioned reasons)

Comment: @M.M following your lead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this:

```
int x[], y[];
```

by:

```
int * x;
int * y;
```

It is going to work. Your solution doesn't work because when you allocate the memory space for the object the computer has to know exactly how big space should be allocated. And the size of x[] and y[] is not defined when you create the object.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you compile in lax mode and gcc plays extension tricks with you in the first place. If you add -pedantic to compile it starts disclosing that it treats x[] as 0-size array that should be rejected.

Fix that part first, then is still have problems ask again.